# Is there any way to find out if there is an open wrapper transaction while inside a trigger?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

When we are inside a trigger and have a transaction open before entering the trigger, the @@TranCount shows 1, same as when we don't have that transaction open.
So Is there any way to find out if there is an open wrapper transaction in this case?

PS: I have a table that fires this trigger. this table can be manipulated in different places with/without wrapper transaction. I need to know about the number of trans while inside the trigger to do proper action like rolling back the trans or leaving it.

Comment: *every* trigger fires within the context of a transaction. There's no way to detect whether that transaction was explicitly opened.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about this behaviour, and I can confirm that it is as observed in SQL Server.

```
  create table test (id int identity, t varchar(23))

  create trigger trg_inser on test after insert as
   select @@TRANCOUNT

   -- test 1
   insert into test(t) values ('test')
   --=> returns 1

  -- test 2
    begin transaction
    insert into test(t) values ('test')
    rollback
  --=> also returns 1

  select @@TRANCOUNT
  --=> returns 0
```

[Books online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187844(v=sql.105).aspx) documents this behaviour

> A trigger operates as if there were an outstanding transaction in
>   effect when the trigger is executed. This is true whether the
>   statement firing the trigger is in an implicit or explicit
>   transaction.
>
> When a statement begins executing in autocommit mode, there is an
>   implied BEGIN TRANSACTION to allow the recovery of all modifications
>   generated by the statement if it encounters an error. This implied
>   transaction has no effect on the other statements in the batch because
>   it is either committed or rolled back when the statement completes.
>   This implied transaction is still in effect, however, when a trigger
>   is called.

I don't think you will be able to differentiate between whether the transaction is explicit or implicit while you are in the trigger.

I suspect what you might need to do is some kind of a try...catch inside the trigger code that handles an error raised during a trigger